# Как построить вертикальную линию на графике в Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly

может быть кто то в курсе как построить вертикальную линию на графике в python , и изменить цвет таким образом как здесь :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

график строю следующим образом :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

table = pd.read_excel('c:/.../plot_usa.xls')
x = table.values[:, 0]
z = table.values[:, 1]
y = table.values[:, 2]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.plot(x, z)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вертикальную линию нарисовать можно так:

```
plt.axvline(x=...) #вместо многоточия - значение по оси абсцисс.
```

Что касается разделения по цвету - рисуйте до нужного значения график одним цветом, а потом другим. так будет проще всего. Цвет линии можете установить в методе plot:

```
plt.plot(x, y, color='r')
```